# CFlint in Visual Studio Code: There was a problem with CFLint. spawn java.exe ENOENT

Tags: visual-studio-code, cflint

I'm trying to run CFLint in VSCode on Windows 10, but keep getting the following error:

```
There was a problem with CFLint. spawn java.exe ENOENT
```

What I tried so far:

- Set the "JAVA_HOME" environment variable to the sdk Folder of my
  Lucee installation (it's the only installed jdk on this machine)
- Added %JAVA_HOME%\bin to my "PATH" variable

I did this for system and user variables in all combinations (only user, only system, both)

Tried the `cflint.javaPath` property in VSCode's settings.json (with and without /bin)

So far nothing helped. The environment variables seem to work fine, if I run `javac -version` from the command line, the version number is displayed (1.8.0_172).

Could this be a problem with Lucee's/Tomcat's jdk? Or maybe a Windows 10-Issue?

Comment: Hey Did you get this one working?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to provide the path to the executable file - not only the path to the JAVA installation like

```
 "cflint.javaPath": "D:\\JAVA\\jdk11.0.6_10\\bin\\java.exe"
```